# Java - reading wrong characters from file

Tags: java

I want to write a program that reads a text from a file character by character and counts how frequently each character occurs.

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class text {

    public static void frequency (char[] array, int k)
    {
        int ok=0;
        for (char i ='a'; i<='z'; i++)
        {
            ok=0;
            for (int j=0; j<k; j++)
                if (i==array[j])
                    ok++;
            if (ok!=0)
            {
                System.out.println (i + " appears for " + ok + " times");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Diana\\workspace\\Text\\src\\FileInput"));
        char[] array = new char [100]; 
        int k=0;

        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            array[k] = in.next().charAt(k);
            k++;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
            System.out.print (array[i]);
        in.close();
        frequency (array, k);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't read all the values from my file. If I have for example *Good Morning* it only reads *Go*. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Look at your loop:

```
while (in.hasNext())
{
    array[k] = in.next().charAt(k);
    k++;
}
```

This reads one *token* at a time, and takes the `k`th character from that token. So from "Good Morning" it retrieves character 0 of "Good" (`G`) and character 1 of "Morning" (`o`).

It's not clear why you've got `k` at all, to be honest - but if you just want to read a file into a character array, it's worth using a `Reader` instead - or `Files.readAllLines` if you're using Java 7 or later. For example:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("FileInput"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : lines) {
    builder.append(line);
}
char[] array = builder.toString().toCharArray();
```

(This will skip the line break characters, but that's *probably* what you want.)